# Codeigniter Routing for static pages home page working other routes not pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

When I access localhost:8080/ignite_me it shows me contents of home.php with header and footer but when I try localhost:8080/igniteme/test It gives me Apche 404 page and test.php exist in my views/pages where i have put my home.php

even localhost:8080/igniteme/home is not working but localhost:8080/igniteme shows content of home.php

routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Pages.php

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

        public function view($page = 'home')
        {
            if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter



            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        }
}
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/igniteme/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I am unable to understand why home.php works with localhost:8080/ignite_me and why not with localhost:8080/igniteme/home or any other page is not working
I have copied .htaccess from some other stack overflow question it was not working even with default one.

here is link to my complete codeignite folder [igniteme](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=22361987214537010816)

Comment: Have u change something in autoload and config file ?

Comment: yes I have updated config.php changes in question and  I have edited autoload.php  `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Comment: Test.php exist in views/page folder?

Comment: Yes test.php and home.php both exist in views/pages

Comment: @AbhinavSuryawanshi What version of codeigniter you using?

Comment: try this:`$route['test'] = 'Your controller/method'`

Comment: @AbhinavSuryawanshi are you using wamp?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I am using codeigniter 3.0.4

Comment: `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` has to be at the end, after all other routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using wamp I use this htaccess below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure in main directory.

Also in wamp make sure **YOU HAVE ENABLED APACHE MOD REWRITE**

Scroll/click and go down the list to you find `rewrite_module` click on it then go and restart wamp.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for noob question how do I enable mod rewrite in apache

Comment: @AbhinavSuryawanshi I added image when you get to list go down to the rewrite module and click on it and restart wamp once click on it.

Comment: I tried above solution with apache rewrite mode on but dint work

Comment: @AbhinavSuryawanshi with your test.php controller make sure is Test.php first letter on class and file name upper case.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/igniteme/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Comment: change $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';   to this  $route['default_controller'] = 'Pages/view';

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'Pages/view' dint help

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /igniteme/test was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 8080

Comment: what is ur controller name

Comment: the controller name is Pages .

Comment: so you try this $route['default_controller'] = 'Pages/view';

Answer (score 1):

Lets Start With Simple Approach

I am assuming that **ignite_me** is your project folder and in views folder
you have two files test.php and home.php and by default there is welcome.php file.

Now Starting Configure Your routes

1.First when you hit the url with  `localhost:8080/ignite_me` it shows you welcome.php file

As there is a controller for welcome
 Now first decide which controller you want to make default 
 let assume you have set controller to test so every time you hit url
 test view will open
 for configuration like this

In routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "test";
```

Now every time it refers to views test.php
if you want to access like this
    `localhost:8080/ignite_me/index.php/test.php` it redirect to same

Now for Removing `index.php` we should use `.htaccess` file
in

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now you can access it again
`localhost:8080/ignite_me/index.php/test.php` it gives you 404 not found error
`localhost:8080/ignite_me/test.php` it gives you that page

**Genereal Ways for route is**

`localhost:8080/ignite_me/[controller]/views`

Comment: I have edited .htaccess as per stackoverflow answer, config.php to have base_url, autoload.php for url helper and database.php

please have  a look at my .htaccess and let me know if changes are required

Comment: I deeply appreciate your efforts. I am still trying to resolve it but somehow its minor mistake that I am not able to identify. Please find my complete project here 
[link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=22361987214537010816)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when I moved a codeigniter 2 app from a xampp in windows to a ubuntu server 14.04 LTS

my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

$config['index_page'] = ''; //blank so index.php wouldn't show inline with .htaccess file

I had routes enable and was getting a 404 on everything but my welcome controller

What I did was to make sure mod_rewrite was enable and set the following configuration on /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Right under “DocumentRoot /var/www/html” add the following lines below:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Save and exit the nano editor via CTRL-X, “y” and ENTER.

And restart the service: sudo service apache2 restart

Hope it does the trick for you